# Twilio Called Id

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have the following method which is hit when on my Twilio number is called:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Merge(string from, string to)
    {
        string outgoingPhoneNumber = "+1xxxxxxx";

        var response = new TwilioResponse();

        Number n = new Number(outgoingPhoneNumber);
        response.Dial(n);

        return TwiML(response);
    }
```

How do I add a called id to this response do the person receiving the call does not see the original number?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Thanks to the following:
https://gist.github.com/dchanTwilio/d86f40b340e29e729473

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Merge(string from, string to)
    {
        string outgoingPhoneNumber = "+1xxxxxxxxxx";

        var response = new TwilioResponse();

        Number n = new Number(outgoingPhoneNumber);
        var dialAttributes = new
        {
            callerId = "+1nnnnnnnnnn",
        };
        response.Dial(n, dialAttributes);

        return TwiML(response);
    }
```

Comment: For further reference, the attributes you can set when you use `<Dial>` are available in the documentation here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial